# Microsoft Bot Framework - Dialog PostToUser

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am trying the [dialog chain](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html#Fluent). What exactly should this sample do? When I tried it I got no result.

```
    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Message> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;

        if (message.Text == "start")
        {
            var query = from x in new PromptDialog.PromptString("p1", "p1", 1)
                        from y in new PromptDialog.PromptString("p2", "p2", 1)
                        select string.Join(" ", x, y);
            query.PostToUser();
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
```

Bot Tester:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post the code here, rather than an image of it.

Comment: Ok. I posted the code instead of a screenshot. Am I expecting people to edit the code that is why you told me to paste it instead of an image?